# Simulate mouse enter/out on array of divs with delay

Tags: jquery

I would like to end up with divs that loop mouse enter and out on load, one by one, with delay after each. Here is a start of what I am working with.

```js
var slides = $(".gallery_slide");
$.each(slides, function(index, value) {


});
```

```css
.gallery_slide {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery_slide:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery_slide">1</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">2</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">3</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">4</div>
```

Comment: @Micor Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have something like this

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/u9jse5j1/4/)**

```
var slides = $(".gallery_slide");
var delay=500;
 slides.each(function(){ 
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        'background-color':'green'
    },500,function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");

    });
    delay += 500;
});
```

**UPDATE WITH LOOP ANIMATION**

**[WORKING FIDDLE 2](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/u9jse5j1/25/)**

```
var slides = $(".gallery_slide");
var delay=1000;
var i=0;
function doLoop(){

 slides.each(function(){ 
    $(this).delay(delay).animate({
        'background-color':'green'
    },1000,function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
      console.log(i);
        if(i==slides.length-1){
            i=0;
        delay=1000;
        doLoop();
        }
      else{
          i++;
       }
    });

    delay += 1000;

});
}

doLoop();
```

Comment: Thank for your reply and working fiddle. It works as intended but only doing a single pass, not looping over and over. I am sorry if I was not clear in my questions but that is what I meant by "loop".

Comment: @Micor I have updated the code with working fiddle in **UPDATE 2** that provides loop animation. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeColor(obj, index){

    setTimeout('$(".gallery_slide:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')").toggleClass(\'gallery_slide_hover\')', index*1000);

    setTimeout('$(".gallery_slide:nth-child(' + (index+1) + ')").toggleClass(\'gallery_slide_hover\')', (index*1000) + 1000 );

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var slides = $(".gallery_slide");
    $.each(slides, function(index, value) {

        //$(this).toggleClass('gallery_slide_hover');

        changeColor($(this), index);

    });

});




</script>
<style type="text/css">
.gallery_slide {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}

.gallery_slide_hover {
  background-color: green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="gallery_slide" style="display: none;">0</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">1</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">2</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">3</div>
<div class="gallery_slide">4</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It looks like it will play sequence once and not loop, playing over and over, which is what I am trying to accomplish. Also, notice that #4 never gets hover effect.